# Problems with reseting the git cherry-pick

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I made some code adjustments to evaluate some functionality in our software. This changes were made to a version of software let say dev_1. We have the official version of the software in CVS, so I checked out dev_1, initiated a git repo and made a few commits. Now my colleague comes and say "hey, I made some adjustment in the algorithm and I would like to know how your evaluation looks like with my version of the code, my version is in CVS ad dev_2."

So I checked out dev_2 from CVS and intialized the git repo. Now I need to apply my changes that I made to dev_1 to dev_2. I decided to cherrypick the commits from dev_1 repo and apply them to dev_2.

However I made some error during cherrypicking merge and now my dev_2 working directry seems to be changed and I don't know how to get to the state where it was before I attempted to cherry-pick.

Is there some way, how to get to the state before cherry-picking?
What is a difference between cherry-pick --abort and cherry-pick --quit (none seems to help)?
And finally, do you think that may approach to solve this problem is good or is there some more simple approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First do `git status` to verify the state. Closely inspect what it prints.

- If it tells you you're on a branch "master" just have some werid (for you) state of files, do

  ```
  git reset --hard
  ```

  to revert the index and the work tree back to the state of the tip of the checked out branch "master".
- If it tells you you're in a "detached HEAD" state, do

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```

  and then proceed as in the first case.

More info on resetting is in the great ["Reset Demystified"](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) article.